# How to find the location where exception occurred in VS C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am getting this exception:

```
Microsoft C++ exception: std:out_of_range at memory location 0xBlahBlahBlah
```

How can I find this location in my code?

Comment: Choose "break" from the dialog, if I remember correctly.

Comment: You are not remembering it correctly. There is no dialog.

Comment: There is a dialog if you're using the Visual Studio debug runtime library.

Comment: What is the deal with downvoting here? If answer is obvious then please let me know. Since VS is showing this address I assume that it must be useful for something. Assembly instructions at this address contain only pure assembly instructions without any debug info. I hope that there is some way to find where exactly this exception is coming from.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to enable the "Break When Thrown" for everything in the Exception Settings. It will have a list of exception types that can be turned on via checkboxes. I usually will turn them all on and go. You may get a few handled exceptions along the way but you shouldn't miss the problem one.

You can find it under: `Debug->Windows->Exception Settings`

Once you're done, I recommend returning it to its default settings (there's a graphical button for it) so you don't keep breaking every time a handled exception is thrown.

Comment: I am currently using VS2013 and this setting is in Debug->Exceptions... There is only option to break when std::exception is thrown. I see multiple thrown exceptions in visual studio output window but debugger does not break.

Answer (score 0):

Here are problem resolution steps:

1. Find memory location displayed in "exception: EEEE at memory location 0xXXXXX" location In disassembly window.
2. Set breakpoint at that location and run program until it breaks.
3. Check call stack to find the function that actually threw the exception.

For some reason debugger did not break when std::out_of_range exception was thrown even though debugger exception settings were set to break when std::exception was thrown.

Answer (score -1):

My approach is setting up a break point somewhere, and then press keep pressing F10 until it throw the exception. Now you know where the bug is.

Comment: Not a very good approach when you have thousands of lines of code with loops and recursion.

Answer (score -2):

This error is a run time logical error which can happen in many cases and to find it you should trace your code and look for some logical errors. e.g.

```
int x[4];
x[5] = 1;
```

int this case you are using a memory unit which is not allowed.

Comment: That will not throw an `out_of_range` exception.  What will throw one is using various STL container's `at()` function (for example `std::vector`), and the index is out of bounds.